# Problem with mosfet driver circuit/switching

Tags: mosfet, switching, mosfet-driver

I have the following driver circuit used for switching very high current n-channel mosfets

Here's their datasheet
https://www.littelfuse.com/~/media/electronics/datasheets/discrete_mosfets/littelfuse_discrete_mosfets_n-channel_trench_gate_ixfn420n10t_datasheet.pdf.pdf )

Here's the circuit that I am trying to build

[image]

After trying to build a prototype on a breadboard, I've found that there is no voltage drop across the 1k resistor that is connected to the 2n7000 transistor. As a result, Vgs=0 no matter what the output of the inverter is (High=5 V, Low= 0V). Here's the datasheet of the 2n7000: https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/NDS7002A-D.PDF

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong with this circuit? I don't think I can ground the source of the 2n70000 because then the driver will share a common ground with the very high current power supply.

Comment: Are you connecting the source to the emitter of the optocoupler?

Comment: @Blue_Electronx wouldn't that just ground the source? If I do that I get Vgs=0 for inverter output=0, and Vgs = 2 V for inverter output= 2 V. For some reason, the inverter output lowers dramatically. In addition, the 10 V regulator gets messed up and starts outputitng 3.5 V.

Comment: Define “very high current”. How fast are you switching?

Comment: @winny roughly 400 A. I'm switching about once every 30 s

Comment: What do you measure on your +5V, + 10 V rails? How do you power the inverter going to the 2N7000 gate?

Comment: @winny +5 and +10 V rails are measuring what they should. The inverter is being powered from the 5 V rail

Comment: Please draw a schematic or exactly what you have built. Use the schematic editor here by pressing edit and click on the schematic symbol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source did, in fact, need to be connected to ground although the 10k resistor was drawing too much current. Switched to a 180k resistor and everything started working as expected.